# VSCode API: Access the minimap

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any way to access the "minimap" that optionally appears next to the scroll bar on the right hand side of the editor?

Preferably I would like to access that panel's width in pixels.

The best I could do to get the values I want is to read the current editor configuration (also settable from the vscode settings UI/JSON).

```js
const editorConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('editor');
const minimapOn = editorConfig.get("minimap.enabled");
const minimapWidth = editorConfig.get("minimap.maxColumn");
```

But this only lists the maximum width, not the current one.

Comment: what are you going to do if it is 100px wide

Comment: @rioV8 I don't wish to change it's value. I want to read it to better style text in an open text editor. Normally it seems to be around 120 px wide. Perhaps I can bet on it always being this wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Configuring the Width of the Editor's Minimap

---

The Minimaps with is configurable, not by pixels, but by characters.
The reason it is configurable by characters is because it gives developers a way of setting the *minimap's width* to the exact width that there longest lines of code are. This is beneficial, as it makes the minimap as wide as needed, without taking up any unnecessary space.

###### *Below is the setting that changes the width of the editor's minimap.*

```
// @file Globally Scoped "settings.json" file
{
    "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 75
}
```

###### *75 can be set to any amount of characters you choose.*

---

#### Now the part about the API

Anytime you have a setting that does what you want, you can use the API to apply it to your extension. I don't want to continue explaining anything byond the scope of this question, so I will provide a link to the documentation that covers the method used to change a setting using the **VS Code API**, and a snippet showing you how to use the method to change the *minimap's columns width*.

---

###### Below shows the code an extension might include to change the size of the minimap.

```
    await vscode.workspace
        .getConfiguration()
        .update(
            'editor.minimap.maxColumn', 
            100, 
            vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global
        );
```

NOTE: I wrote the example above off the top of my head. I know that the semantics are all correct, but you will probably have to play with it to get it to do exactly what it is your going for.

###### Here are a couple links to help you understand what your doing.

**["vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration)** This is can be interpreted as the base of program-interface that changes settings. From this part of the API, a few methods, objects, constants, and events extend, all of which are used to set, get, and mutate configurations within VS Code.

**["The Configuration target"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ConfigurationTarget)**  sets the settings.json file you are targeting. Global is a good bet, I prefer *"workspace"* (which is not the same as *"workspace folder"*.

Comment: This answers most of what I was looking for but I was more after if there was a way to access the current attributes such as current width/height. `maxColumn` only specifies the maximum width.

Comment: On a second look, the minimap seems to change depending on the window size. I am mainly after the physical width of the minimap panel in the UI.

Comment: Well then don't set it to be proportional

Comment: You can set the scale: `"editor.minimap.scale"`

Comment: and you can set the size: `"editor.minimap.size"`

Comment: The Size will change how maxColumn adjusts the width. You cannot adjust the height of the minimap. The VSCode API doesn't really do that sort of thing. The API is more of an interactive api, rather than a stuctrual (graphics/style) api.